# Is it possible to convert an octagonal electrical box so that it can house 2 Duplex outlets without changing the shape of the box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I currently have 1 Duplex outlet installed in an octagonal box mounted on the ceiling.  I need to add another outlet to make it a 2 gang.  However, I can't find a cover that will hold a 2 gang outlet for octagonal box.  Is this possible without changing the box?

Comment: never seen a 2-gang cover for 3-0 or 4-0 boxes. probably not large enough to support 2 duplex receptacles

Answer (score 5):

This product by Hubbell is about the only thing I can think of that will provide the equivalent of a two-gang duplex (quad) receptacle on an octagon box.

http://ecatalog.hubbell-wiring.com/press/pdfs/H4416R.pdf

[image]

Amazon.com even has them: [http://www.amazon.com/Hubbell-HBL415BK-4-Plex-Receptacle-5-15R/dp/B00NGPR9MI/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1440803585&sr=8-15&keywords=hubbell+4-plex](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NGPR9MI)

Comment: nice find. That is a nice unit and should be exactly what the OP needs. Looks expensive though!

Comment: Under $25, but if it solves a problem it's worth it IMO.

Comment: Great find!  That is awesome

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. National Electrical Code has capacity limits depending on the volume of the box. Standard practice would be to install a second box next to the first. If you happen to weld then you could: cut off a third from 2 octagonal 4 inch boxes (keep the 2 screw tabs in place), clamp the two cut boxes together and weld the joint. You now have an original, one of a kind round, Duplex, box! (Patent Pending!)